# Why did position close very quickly on FTSE

Tags: stocks

Using MT4 on the FTSE, on `2019-10-16`, I set an automated position with:

```
- Open: 7203.7
- Stop Loss: 7193.7
- Take Profit: 7208.9
```

At `06:15:07` the position opened at `7203.8` and at `06:15:49` it closed at `7204.3`

Why?

On the 1 minute time frame, the candle at `2019-10-16 06:15` shows:

```
- Open: 7199.8
- High: 7205.8
- Low: 7198.8
- Close: 7204.0
```

Comment: I believe this was because of the spread being greater in the early, pre-market hours.

Comment: What time zone are you quoting this in?

Comment: Timezone of the market is UTC - I am in BST (UTC+1)